# Trouble communicating with Pyserial and Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  String inComing;
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  while(1)
  {
    if (Serial.available())
    {
      inComing = Serial.readString();
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      if (inComing == "GO")
      {
        Serial.println("GO");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Python:

```
import serial
import time

duino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=None)


def sync():
    mark = "GO"
    duino.write(mark.encode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(1)
    while (duino.inWaiting() == 0):  # Code Getting Stuck here!!
##        if (duino.inWaiting() > 0): Redundant
##            break
        pass

    inComing = duino.readline().decode().strip('\r\n')
    print(inComing)   ## Debug
    if (inComing == mark):
        return 1
    else:
        print("Not Yet")
        return 0


if __name__ == "__main__" :

    chk = 0
    while (not(chk)):
        print("syncing")  # Debug
        chk = sync()

    print("sync complete")
```

I want the arduino to wait in setup() for the command from the Pi before entering loop().  The Pi is also supposed to receive a reply from the Arduino, then start logging the received data. For some reason my program hangs when I call inWaiting() on the Pi side.  When I run the debugger and step through it, everything executes just fine.  When I run the code, it gets stuck.  The arduino side works perfectly through serial monitor as well.
Somehow the pySerial misses the incoming data. I have also tried sending a response every 100mS from the arduino but it still doesn't seem to get through.
What could be causing inWaiting() to miss data in the buffer?

Comment: In your sync() function,  try increasing the sleep time, say, time.sleep(5). (You can adjust afterwards.) It's possible that you're not waiting long enough going by your experience that it works when debugging step by step.

Comment: You don't need the brackets in Python's conditionals.. Also, add a small sleep to your polling loop (checking inWaiting()) to reduce CPU load.

Comment: @hikerjobs: The issue definitely lies somewhere in there but I have yet to find a good sleep time to correct it.  On the other hand, I just tried it with a user prompt at the start of sync() and it seems to work fine that way.  Seems the break in execution is what is missing.

Comment: I found a better way to synchronize the two that seems to be more reliable [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073086/wait-on-arduino-auto-reset-using-pyserial?rq=1[/link].  Thanks for the feedback guys!